# Hadoop YARN: How to force a Node to be Marked "LOST" instead of "SHUTDOWN"?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I'm troubleshooting YARN application failures that happen when nodes are LOST, so I'm trying to recreate this scenario. But I'm only able to force nodes to be SHUTDOWN instead of LOST. I'm using AWS EMR, and I've tried:

- logging into a node and doing a `shutdown -h now`
- logging into a node and doing `sudo stop hadoop-yarn-nodemanager` and `sudo stop hadoop-hdfs-datanode`
- killing the NodeManager with a `kill -9 <pid>`

Those result in SHUTDOWN nodes but not LOST nodes.

**How do I create a LOST node in AWS EMR?**

Comment: Have you tried bringing the interface down on the node e.g. `ifconfig eth0 down` ?

Comment: No, that's a good suggestion. I'll give that a try.

Comment: That works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, bringing the interface down on the node induces the node LOST scenario e.g:

`ifconfig eth0 down`

Answer (score 2):

NodeManager is `LOST` means that ResourceManager haven't received heartbeats from it for a duration of `nm.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms` milliseconds (default is 10 minutes). You may wanna try to block outbound traffic from NM node to RM's IP (or just the port if RM node runs multiple services), but I'm not sure how exactly that can be accomplished in AWS. Maybe use iptables, for example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <RM's IP> --dport <RM's port> -j DROP
```

Comment: When I do something like `shutdown -h now` on the machine running the NM the node is marked `SHUTDOWN` almost immediately. Do you know how the SHUTDOWN state differs from LOST?

Comment: They differ because during shutdown NM executes a `ShutdownHook` which, in part, signals back to RM that this NM instance is being gracefully shutdown. The LOST state signifies that RM has basically lost track of NM status. You can review possible NM transitions by looking at the code https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-3.0.0/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/rmnode/RMNodeImpl.java#L188, or searching for some nice RM State Machine diagram elsewhere on the web.